# NodeJS Express App still works despite forgetting app.listen()

Tags: node.js, express

I had a strange problem with my routes in my NodeJS project and it turns out that the reason was that I forgot to add `app.listen()` at the end.

Everything else was written and working normally though. That is to say, my pages were being served and all the code seemed fine.

But I'm puzzled. Why did my code work before I had `app.listen()` in there?

I don't intend to post the whole project, I'm just looking for helpful suggestions and scenarios people can think of regarding how this can possibly happen.

Answer (score 0):

Really can't give a definitive answer without the code, but it might have to do with your development environment. You might have included app.listen() in a previous iteration and executed the program. In some operating systems, closing out of terminal won't kill the current process, but keep it running. So, your server could have been running the whole time, and you were getting routing problems because whenever you ran your new code, it wasn't listening on the proper port.

Though, this might not apply to your situation.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I was thinking maybe it had something to do with that the code was living in my WAMP folder